# How to get json parent property instead of taken all of same property name in json4s

Tags: json, scala

I use json4s and scala 2.11.12

the exmaple json is:

```
     { "name": "joe",
       "children": [
         {
           "name": "Mary",
           "age": 5
         },
         {
           "name": "Mazy",
           "age": 3
         }
       ]
     }
```

when I want to get the name, instead of get parent name "joe", it give me all names of parents and child by(I use json4s library http://json4s.org/)

```
compact(render(json \\ "name"))
```

it return me :

res2: String = {"name":"joe","name":"Mary","name":"Mazy"}

I only need {"name":"joe"}

I　only need parent name, How to get only parent name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val json = "..."
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
val parent: JValue = json \ "name"
```

The `\` method which with the native implementation of JSON4S will be `lift-json` based, will look up a field value by name inside a JSON object. Note, your json needs to be a `JValue` before you can do this, so from a `val jsonData: String` you need to call `val json = Json.parse(jsonData)` to get the initial `JValue`.

The double backslash `\\` method will find all children of the JSON that have a given property, so that's why you are getting the entire set of `JObject` matches back.